# Black square instead of image

Tags: android-layout, android, galaxy

I have problem that on Galaxy S3 some images are replaced by black square. On other devices it's working correctly.
Some thoughts what can cause this problem?

[image]

EDIT:
Some code:

```
final ImageView subscribe = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.subscribe);
final boolean isSubscribed = isSubscribed();
subscribe.setImageResource(isSubscribed ? R.drawable.star_yellow : R.drawable.star_gray);
```

Layout:

```
<ImageView
     android:id="@+id/subscribe"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignParentRight="true" 
     android:padding="20dip"
     android:src="@drawable/star_gray"/>
```

Comment: Is this an ImageButton? If yes, did you try to set android:background="@null"?

Comment: what is it supposed to be ? how do you set the image ?

Comment: post the code for the squares...always post the code. Also is there any animation taking place?

Comment: I added some code. Strange is that this doesn't work only on galaxy S3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed imageview to imagebutton and it works now

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem by testing some GIF image before, just change back to PNG, then it was ok.

If the image is already in PNG, maybe possible to re-edit the image in case...

Answer (score -2):

just Uninstall and then install the application and its working fine..